# How to use AJV to validate page id against navigation ids in JSON schema

Tags: javascript, node.js, jsonschema, json-schema-validator, ajv

I am trying to create ajv based json schema validations. I want to validate if page.id value is equal to any one navigation.ids present in an array. For example:

```
`"page": {
    "id": "1"
},
"navigation": [
    {"id": "1"},
    {"id": "2"},
    {"id": "3"}
]`
```

Can anyone please help suggest how can I validate this using ajv.

I was able to check if page.id is equal to first/second/third element in array, but if I specifically mention the element index while checking. However, the requirement is to check if id is equal to any of the element inside the array. Note: the size of navigation array is not limited or fixed.

```
`page: {
    type: "object",
    properties: {
      id: {
        type: "string",
        const: { $data: "/navigation/0/id"},
      }
`
```